# How to optimize a for loop in python that references values in a data frame that are updated in the loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

The code below first updates the signal column with a `1` or `-1` if certain conditions are met, otherwise the signal column is set to `0`.

In the for-loop, the signal column gets updated to the previous signal value if certain conditions are met. I would like to replace the for-loop with a faster solution that is still able to update the signal column with the previous signal value considering the previous signal value could be updated through the process.

```
df['signal'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['ind_1'] == 1, df['ind_2'] <= threshold), 1, 0)
df['signal'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['ind_1'] == -1, df['ind_2'] >= 100 - threshold), -1, df['signal'])
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.at[i, 'signal'] == 0 and df.at[i - 1, 'signal'] != 0:
        if df.at[i, 'ind_1'] == 0:
            df.at[i, 'signal'] = df.at[i - 1, 'signal']
```

Comment: Might be useful: [cs95's answer on "How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas"; tldr DON'T](/a/55557758/4518341)

Comment: It might help to make a [mre]. For specifics see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to manipulate data in a dataframe is through [vectorization](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-vectorization/).
Let me explain using below code for 1,000,000 records:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import time

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ind_1': np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(1000000, )),
    'ind_2': np.random.randint(0, 101, size=(1000000, ))
})
threshold = 40
df['signal'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['ind_1'] == 1, df['ind_2'] <= threshold), 1, 0)
df['signal'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['ind_1'] == -1, df['ind_2'] >= 100 - threshold), -1, df['signal'])

df2 = df.copy()    #duplicate dataframe for comparison
```

I'm using `df` to measure the time taken for the original solution.
And the duplicated `df2` to measure time taken for my proposed solution.

In my proposed solution, I'm using `df2['signal_shift1'] = df2['signal'].shift(1)` to move the `signal` column down 1 row, so that the record can be compared across the same row.

Then your original conditions:
A: `df.at[i, 'signal'] == 0`  and
B: `df.at[i - 1, 'signal'] != 0` and
C: `df.at[i, 'ind_1'] == 0`

becomes this, comparable on the same row:
A&C: `df2['signal'].abs() + df2['ind_1'].abs() == 0` and
B: `df2['signal_shift1'] != 0`
*Note that I've combined conditions A==0 and C==0 to become abs(A)+abs(C)==0*

```py
#original solution (using df)
ti = time()
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.at[i, 'signal'] == 0 and df.at[i - 1, 'signal'] != 0:
        if df.at[i, 'ind_1'] == 0:
            df.at[i, 'signal'] = df.at[i - 1, 'signal']
print('Time taken original solution: {:.3f} sec'.format(time() - ti))

#proposed solution (using df2)
ti = time()
df2['signal_compare'] = 0    #initialize break condition
while not df2['signal_compare'].equals(df2['signal']):
    df2['signal_compare'] = df2['signal'].copy()    #condition to break while-loop
    df2['signal_shift1'] = df2['signal'].shift(1)
    df2.at[0, 'signal_shift1'] = df2.at[0, 'signal']    #to remove null value after .shift(1)
    df2['signal'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df2['signal'].abs() + df2['ind_1'].abs() == 0, df2['signal_shift1'] != 0), df2['signal_shift1'], df2['signal']).astype('int')
print('Time taken proposed solution: {:.3f} sec'.format(time() - ti))

#check if original solution and proposed solution are the same
print('Output columns are the same:', df['signal'].equals(df2['signal']))
print(df2)
```

The output shows that the proposed solution is completed within a shorter time, while having the same column `signal` results. It's very obvious that **vectorization is much faster** than for-loop iteration!

```
Time taken original solution: 6.501 sec
Time taken proposed solution: 0.202 sec
Output columns are the same: True

        ind_1  ind_2  signal  signal_compare  signal_shift1
0          -1     80      -1              -1           -1.0
1           0     14      -1              -1           -1.0
2           0     14      -1              -1           -1.0
3           1     46       0               0           -1.0
4           0     23       0               0            0.0
...       ...    ...     ...             ...            ...
999995      0     70       0               0            0.0
999996     -1     88      -1              -1            0.0
999997      0     73      -1              -1           -1.0
999998     -1     39       0               0           -1.0
999999     -1     83      -1              -1            0.0

[1000000 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: if row index 3 signal = 0 and ind_1 = 0 in your example, would this row get updated with your code? I need all rows that meet the conditions to be updated

Comment: Yea, you're right! The 'signal' value in previous rows do change, so I'd need to apply the vectorization a few times, let me explore!

Comment: I've re-used the DataFrame code from @MariaKozlova (thanks buddy!)

Answer (score 0):

`shift` method seems to do the trick.

I've generated a mock dataset like this:

```
threshold = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ind_1": np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=(10, )),
    "ind_2": np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, ))
})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ind_1  ind_2
0     -1     31
1      1     68
2      0     78
3      0     11
4      0     29
5     -1     81
6      0      2
7      0      3
8      1     99
9      0     55
```

Then shifting and checking all the conditions:

```
# your signal calculations
df['signal'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['ind_1'] == 1, df['ind_2'] <= threshold), 1, 0)
df['signal'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['ind_1'] == -1, df['ind_2'] >= 100 - threshold), -1, df['signal'])

# for-loop replacement
substitute_idxs = (df["signal"] == 0) & (df["signal"].shift(1) != 0) & (df["ind_1"] == 0)
print(df)
print(substitute_idxs)
df["signal"][substitute_idxs] = df["signal"].shift(1)[substitute_idxs]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ind_1  ind_2  signal
0     -1     31       0
1      1     68       0
2      0     78       0
3      0     11       0
4      0     29       0
5     -1     81      -1
6      0      2       0
7      0      3       0
8      1     99       0
9      0     55       0

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

   ind_1  ind_2  signal
0     -1     31       0
1      1     68       0
2      0     78       0
3      0     11       0
4      0     29       0
5     -1     81      -1
6      0      2      -1
7      0      3       0
8      1     99       0
9      0     55       0
```

- First part of output is initial dataframe.
- Second part - indices which satisfy all conditions and where signal needs to be replaces are marked `True`.
- Third part - dataframe with replaced signals (signal at 6th row was replaced to the previous value -1).

Comment: index 7 row should also be updated to -1 since it meets the conditions and the previous signal is now -1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have come up:

```
prev_signal = 0
signal_values = df['signal'].values
ind_1_values = df['ind_1'].values

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if signal_values[i] == 0 and prev_signal != 0:
        if ind_1_values[i] == 0:
            signal_values[i] = prev_signal
    prev_signal = signal_values[i]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).